# Aggregation in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Below is a document from my database:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("58635ac32c9592064471cf5b"), 
    "agency_code" : "v5global", 
    "client_code" : "whirlpool", 
    "project_code" : "whirlpool", 
    "date" : {
        "datetime" : 1464739200000.0, 
        "date" : 1464739200000.0, 
        "datejs" : ISODate("2016-06-01T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
        "datetimejs" : ISODate("2016-06-01T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
        "month" : NumberInt(5), 
        "year" : NumberInt(2016), 
        "day" : NumberInt(1)
    }, 
    "user" : {
        "promoter_id" : NumberInt(19), 
        "promoter_name" : "Hira Singh Pawar", 
        "empcode" : "519230"
    }, 
    "counter" : {
        "store_id" : NumberInt(4), 
        "store_name" : "Maya Sales ", 
        "chain_type" : "BS", 
        "address" : "6  Filamingo Market , Hissar", 
        "city" : "Hissar", 
        "state" : "Faridabad", 
        "region" : "North", 
        "sap_code" : "N_Far_91103948_1", 
        "unique_tp_code" : "91103948", 
        "location" : "6"
    }, 
    "insertedon" : {
        "date" : 1464739200000.0, 
        "datejs" : ISODate("2016-06-01T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
        "datetimejs" : ISODate("2016-06-01T00:00:00.000+0000")
    }, 
    "insertedby" : "akshay", 
    "manager" : {
        "manager_id" : NumberInt(5943), 
        "manager_name" : "Sonu Singh"
    }, 
    "type" : "display", 
    "data" : {
        "brand" : "whirlpool", 
        "sku" : "60", 
        "model_name" : "Icemagic Fresh", 
        "sub_cat_name" : "DC", 
        "cat_name" : "Refrigerator", 
        "value" : NumberInt(1)
    }, 
    "IsDeleted" : false
}
```

I want to apply aggregation where I have to group it with `city`, `state` and `region` and if that counter has sold refrigerator I need that details in my result e.g if a counter has sold 2 refrigerators of whirlpool company then I want that to reflect in my result.

A counter can also sell other things like washing machines etc. So if they have sold 2 washing machines I want a result with `{ washingMachine: 2 }`.

I have tried everything and nothing seems to be working here:

```
db.display_mop.aggregate( // Pipeline [ 
    // Stage 1 
    { $match: { "project_code":"whirlpool" } }, 

    // Stage 2 
    { 
        $group: { 
            _id: { 
                "userid": "$user.promoter_id", 
                "userName": "$user.promoter_name", 
                "usercode": "$user.empcode", 
                "storename": "$counter.store_name",
                "address": "$counter.address", 
                "city": "$counter.city", 
                "state": "$counter.state", 
                "region": "$counter.region" 
            } 
        } 
    }, 
], 
// Options 
{ allowDiskUse: true }
```

Comment: Did you try anything? or you just want someone to do it for you? Please put what you have tried so that people can help.

Comment: Yes I have.Below is my code I have tried.I am actually new to mongo but below is my code I am working on.

Comment: db.display_mop.aggregate(

 // Pipeline
 [
  // Stage 1
  {
   $match: {
   "project_code":"whirlpool"
   }
  },

  // Stage 2
  {
   $group: {
   _id:{
   "userid":"$user.promoter_id",
   "userName":"$user.promoter_name",
   "usercode":"$user.empcode",
   "storename":"$counter.store_name",
   "address":"$counter.address",
   "city":"$counter.city",
   "state":"$counter.state",
   "region":"$counter.region"
   }
   }
  },
 ],

 // Options
 {
  allowDiskUse: true
 }

Comment: Well, so each document represents a sold object? I guess you want to group by state, region, country and also counter with number of object sold? What should the end document according to you look like?

Comment: It should be the data as it is in my database but if that counter has sold a refrigerator of whirlpool then the result should have whirlpool with the number of quantity that counter has sold.

Comment: Well, if it is just about getting the count by a certain counter, you can try $sum. Here is something which I appended to your aggregation  db.display_mop.aggregate([{$match: {"project_code": "whirlpool"}},{
 $group: {
  _id: {
   "userid": "$user.promoter_id",
   "userName": "$user.promoter_name",
   "usercode": "$user.empcode",
   "storename": "$counter.store_name",
   "address": "$counter.address",
   "city": "$counter.city",
   "state": "$counter.state",
   "region": "$counter.region"
  },
                count: {$sum:1}
 }}])

Comment: Ofcourse end document can't be in same structure because in aggregation of getting count  or average, it cannot return the same structure. You might want to see example of $project and $addToSet if you want complete data.